# How to display the text first until image retrieve from database sql

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have datalist which is working fine but very slow
I want to first load text after that load image in same datalist

In asp.net c# 
Is it any idea to achieve that 
Thanxs

Comment: Could you share some code that shows what you are trying to do?

Comment: Use the text as the alt attribute of the img.